# Multiple Foreign Keys entry in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

I am having an issue with a projectapp in Django. Basically, what I need to do is creating a page where I display the item contained in a certain flight mission (I am developing the software for a flight school). The models code should be something like this:

models.py

```
class FlightMissionItem(models.Model):
flight_item = models.CharField(max_length=800)


class FlightMission(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pre_flight_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    flight_item = models.ForeignKey(
        FlightMissionItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grading = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=GRADING_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    flight_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    debriefing_comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I am trying to do, is to have multiple flight_item inside the FlightMission model.
I post also the admin models:

admin.py

```
class FlightMissionItemAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
model = FlightMission


class FlightMissionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [FlightMissionItemAdmin]
```

The problem is that, anytime I try to modify the admin.py, I receive an error like this:

```
<class 'flight.admin.FlightMissionItemAdmin'>: (admin.E202) 'flight.FlightMission' has no ForeignKey to 'flight.FlightMission'.
```

The only way I was able to find a loophole in the error was to add another ForeignKey to the FlightMissionItem model. The problem was that basically I was able to loop over just 1 item in the FlightMission later on, so I wasn't able to display anything useful in the HTML.
I hope that is clear, otherwise I'll try to explain myself better.

Comment: Shouldn't `FlightMissionItemAdmin` use `FlightMissionItem` as a model and not `FlightMission`?

Comment: I tried but it still gives me the error. It works only if, inside the model FlightMissionItem I insert a ForeignKey from FlightMission model.